# Is the Grassmannian a Fiber Bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, grassmannian

Let $V$ be a real, finite dimensional, vector space, let $\mathrm {Ind}_k(V)$ be the set of all linearly independent vectors $(v_1,...,v_k)\in V^k$ and let $\pi :\mathrm {Ind}_k(V) \rightarrow \mathrm {Grass}_k (V)$ be the function
$$\pi (v_1,...,v_k)= <v_1,...,v_k>$$
Where $<v_1,...,v_k>$ is the subspace generated by $v_1,...,v_k$. I want to prove that for every smooth path $\sigma : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathrm {Grass}_k (V)$ there is a smooth path $\mu :[0,1] \rightarrow \mathrm {Ind}_k(V)$ such that $\pi \circ \mu = \sigma$.

I read somewhere that fibre bundles have the "path lifting" property. If I could prove that $\pi :\mathrm {Ind}_k(V) \rightarrow \mathrm {Grass}_k (V)$ is a fiber bundle, then Im done. Sadly, I know little about fibre bundles so Im not sure how to prove what I want. The only think I got is
$$\pi ^{-1}(S) = \mathrm {Bases}(S) \cong \mathrm {GL}_k (\Bbb R)  $$

Comment: Offhand, it looks easier (and feasible using only linear algebra and compactness of the unit interval) to show that we can choose ordered bases smoothly for a smooth curve of subspaces of fixed dimension.

Comment: Ok,... could you explain how?

Comment: 1. My prior comment is based on the guess that this is homework. If so, for multiple reasons I'd recommend aiming for as concrete and low-tech a proof as possible. 2. As phrased, this question asks about a high-tech approach. Because of how MSE is structured, it would be misplaced to offer a low-tech answer here. (Separately, I can't commit to writing up an answer.) 3. In any case, it would help prospective answerers to know how you've been introduced to the Grassmannian and the bundle of frames so we know what techniques are available to you. :)

Comment: Is not homework (and a low-tech proof is fine). I have charts for the grassmanian, and my final goal is to prove the tangent space of the grassmanian at a subspace $S$ can be identify with $Hom(S,V/S)$. After much work, I acomplished my goal, only leaving this "path lifting" hole in my writing.

Comment: A simple way to show that $\pi$ forms a fiber bundle is to show that it is a surjective submersion. Since $\pi$ is certainly surjective, you only need to show that the tangent map to $\pi$ has constant rank equal to the dimension of $\mathrm{Ind}_{k}(V)$, or equivalently that the tangent map is surjective on tangent spaces.

Comment: If the fibers were compact, I believe you because Ereshman Theorem. But the fibers are not compact